# Insert Formula in blank cells of specific column

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I want to insert a formula into any blank cells in column A , the formula is

```
=vlookup([cell ref],worksheet,A:Z,2,0)
```

where the cell ref is the adjacent cell in column C. I can't overwrite the entire column as some of the values the formula would return are no longer available. As column C expands each week i can't put a set cell number.

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

We want to fill the empty cells in column **A** with formulas like:

```
=B1+C1
```

This macro:

```
Sub FillStuff()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    r.Formula = "=C1+B1"
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: Thank You, one small issue, if the first cell in A isn't blank the cell reference doesn't match the corresponding cell in column C.

Comment: @Sherbetdab  We can adjust for that.